# Comparing three files in Awk

Tags: shell, awk, gawk

I have three files and I would like to use awk to compare the first two and then update the last one with names that are not matched from the frist file.

File 1: ignore.txt

```
bob
diana
```

File 2: list.txt

```
alice
bob
chris
diana
elvis
```

File 3: names.txt

```
alice
chris
elvis
```

File 2 will have new names added every little while, so I must be able to compare it with both other files and add any new names on that list to names.txt.

This is my script so far, comparing List and ignore is working, but it doesnt do the updating because I still dont understand correctly how to use `getline` and compare the new array against the files in memory.

I'm calling the script like: `awk -f compare ignore.txt list.txt` and it works. If I call it with the extra variable, it doesnt do it: `awk -f compare -v newnames=1 ignore.txt list.txt`.

```
 BEGIN {
  file="list.txt"
  tmpfile="new_list.txt"
  }
# working
FNR == NR { names[$0]++; next }
!names[$0] {
   print > names.txt
}
{ #not working
if (newnames == 1) {
  mvcmd="mv " tmpfile file;
    while ((getline newnames < file) > 0)
      newnames[$0]++; next
     !newnames[$0];
        print > tmpfile 
     system(mvcmd)
     close(dbfile)
  }
```

How can I make it work? The code is not very good because I find it confusing. Sorry.

Comment: If order isn't important you can disregard the contents of `file3` altogether.

Comment: There are very few legitimate reasons to use getline. Make sure you read and FULLY understand all of the pitfalls described at http://awk.info/?tip/getline if you're considering using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common use for `awk`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' file1 file2
alice
chris
elvis
```

It's easier just rewrite the whole `file3` then just updating it:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' file1 file2 > file3
```

**Explanation:**

`NR` is an `awk` variable incremented after every record is read, `FNR` is similar but gets reset to 1 everytime a new file is read. `NR==FNR` can therefor only be True when reading the first file. When reading the first file we create an array `a` where the keys in the array are the lines in the file, as well as storing all the lines from file1 this will remove any duplicates. `next` is a command that makes sure no further blocks get executed on the current record. Once `file1` has been read we just check if the current line in `file2` is found in the array (i.e was in `file1`). The condition `!($0 in a)` has no block to executed so by default `awk` executed `{print $0}`.

There is plenty wrong with your script, the best thing to do would be to read [**Effective Awk Programming**](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/) if you want to learn `awk`.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I am reading the Awk book, but I think I need to try and write some scripts to learn properly.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you need, given how you describe the problem:

```
awk 'FILENAME!=ARGV[3]{seen[$0]++;next} !seen[$0]++' file1 file3 file2
```

To update file3 with the output:

```
awk 'FILENAME!=ARGV[3]{seen[$0]++;next} !seen[$0]++' file1 file3 file2 >> file3
```

It will even remove duplicate new names from file2:

```
$ cat file1
bob
diana

$ cat file2
alice
bill
bob
chris
ted
diana
elvis
ted

$ cat file3
alice
chris
elvis

$ awk 'FILENAME!=ARGV[3]{seen[$0]++;next} !seen[$0]++' file1 file3 file2
bill
ted
```

If all of the values in file3 also exist in file2 but duplicates in file2 are possible then this is all you need:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{seen[$0]++;next} !seen[$0]++' file1 file2 > file3
```

If all of the values in file3 also exist in file2 and duplicates in file2 are not possible, @sudo_O's solution will work just fine.

Comment: I think I understand your solution better now, excpet unsetting the FILENAME: do you mind explaining how this works?

Comment: I'm not unsetting FILENAME. All I'm doing with FILENAME is testing it's value so the script can do something different when FILENAME matches the 3rd argument to the script, i.e. `file2`, vs the first 2 args/files.

Comment: Oh: that is quite clever. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: Upvote for including the `FILENAME` variable. Every other answer I found gave the `NR==FNR` trick, which works great on only two files, or certain multiple file set-ups, but wasn't working for me. Cheers!

Comment: If you have GNU awk you could also consider using `ARGIND==3` instead of `FILENAME==ARGV[3]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do this using `grep`:

```
grep -v -f names.txt <(grep -v -f ignore.txt list.txt) >>  names.txt
```

This would work even if `names.txt` does not exist to begin with.  (Of course, it'd update `names.txt` if new additions are made to `list.txt` and the command is executed again.)

Comment: Thank you. But I am trying to learn awk. But I voted for this.

Comment: Note that if the name `ed` existed in `ignore.txt` then the above would ignore `ted`, `fred`, etc. if they appeared in `list.txt`.